# Conditional inline in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, conditional-statements, inline

I'm trying to figure out a way to display the following RelativeInline only if Person.is_member is True.

Current admin.py:

```
class RelativeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Relative
    fk_name = 'member'

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [RelativeInline,]
    ordering = ('first_name',)
    list_filter = ('is_member',)
    search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name',)
    date_hierarchy = 'member_date'
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'is_member', 'member_date', 'photo')

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

The only hint I've been able to find is that I might be able to override get_formset, but I couldn't find a good example, so my feeble attempt didn't work.

Here's my failed attempt:

```
class RelativeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Relative
    fk_name = 'member'

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ('first_name',)
    list_filter = ('is_member',)
    search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name',)
    date_hierarchy = 'member_date'
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'is_member', 'member_date', 'photo')

    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj.is_member:
            inlines = [RelativeInline,]
        return super(PersonAdmin, self).get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

There are no errors generated by this code, but no inline appears regardless of whether or not Person.is_member is True or False.

---

Update:
A friend suggested I try changing:

```
inlines = [RelativeInline,]
```

to:

```
self.inlines = [RelativeInline,]
```

but to no avail. I also tried:

```
PersonAdmin.inlines = [RelativeInline,]
```

but the result was the same -- no error, no inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to change the whole paradigm and solve my problem a different way. Instead of having a single admin for all Persons with a conditional inline, I decided to:

1. Override the queryset to filter for members-only and keep RelativeInline with the admin for this model
2. Create a proxy model and override its queryset to filter for non-members. The admin for this model does not include RelativeInline.

In the end, I think this is a cleaner approach. Now Members can be maintained, and relatives (non-members) can be added in the inline. The NonMemberAdmin allows for editing non-members.

**models.py:**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_member = models.BooleanField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Members'
        ordering = ('first_name', 'last_name')

class PersonProxy(Person):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name_plural = 'Non-Members'

class Relationship(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Relative(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='relative_member')
    relative = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='relative_relative')
    relationship = models.ForeignKey(Relationship)
```

**admin.py:**

```
class RelativeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Relative
    fk_name = 'member'


class MemberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [RelativeInline,]
    ordering = ('first_name',)
    # list_filter = ('is_member',)
    search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name',)
    # date_hierarchy = 'member_date'
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'member_date')

    def queryset(self, request):
        return (super(MemberAdmin, self).queryset(request)
                .filter(is_member=True, is_active=True))


class NonMemberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ('first_name',)
    search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name',)
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name')

    def queryset(self, request):
        return (super(NonMemberAdmin, self).queryset(request)
                .filter(is_member=False, is_active=True))


admin.site.register(Person, MemberAdmin)
admin.site.register(PersonProxy, NonMemberAdmin)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your original solution was pretty close. If you look in django/contrib/admin/options.py around line 290 you'll see that the inline classes are instantiated when the model admin is instantiated, after which the `inlines` list is ignored. So setting this list later on in get_formsets() has no effect.

However, you're correct that get_formsets() is the thing to override in order to make your inlines conditional. The inline instances are contained in `self.inline_instances`, so to disable them based on the object (e.g. say I want to hide a specific inline on the "add" form) you'd override it like:

```
class MyAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):

    inlines = [MyInline, SomeOtherInline]

    def get_formsets(self, request, obj=None):
        for inline in self.inline_instances:
            if isinstance(inline, MyInline) and obj is None:
                continue
            yield inline.get_formset(request, obj)
```

Comment: update for 2014 and django 1.6:
        `for inline in self.get_inline_instances(request, obj):`

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question's a bit old and the codebase has changed a bit; there's a cleaner point to override things at now: `get_inline_instances`. You can do this:

```
class PersonAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):

inlines = [RelativeInline,]

def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
    to_return = super(MyAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)
    #filter out the RelativeInlines if obj.is_member is false
    if not obj or not obj.is_member:
        to_return = [x for x in to_return if not isinstance(x,RelativeInline)]
    return to_return
```